# Increment Last Number in a Text String in Excel 2007

Tags: excel, numbers, ms-office, excel-2007

I am trying to import large number of data in Opencart. For the product image I should write image path like

catalog/Products/fashion/bags/01.jpg

catalog/Products/fashion/bags/02.jpg

catalog/Products/fashion/bags/03.jpg

catalog/Products/fashion/bags/04.jpg

I know I can increase numbers by dragging the plus (+) icon in sell if there are just numbers.

How can I increase numbers in this case?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

As per this website:

https://exceljet.net/formula/increment-a-number-in-a-text-string

You can do what you are asking for as follows:

Generic Formula:

```
="Item "&TEXT(RIGHT(A1,3)+increment,"000")
```

Specific Example:

```
 ="Item "&TEXT(RIGHT(B5,3)+C5,"000")
```